# How to link into new page using button in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I was trying to make a simple GUI with *wxPython* in which I can switch in between two or more pages using some buttons but I am not able to do so . Please tell me something by which I can link those pages using  a button in *wxPython*. I have tried to google it but there was nothing I can find useful regarding this. Tell me if this is possible to link 2 pages or not.

Comment: Try to use wxGlade

Comment: Do you mean `wxNotebook` pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly, you are going to make a windows GUI which is included by a menu consists of some items!. As mentioned in the comment, personally I use wxGlage which is a GUI designer written in Python with the popular GUI toolkit wxPython, that helps you create wxWidgets/wxPython user interfaces. At the moment it can generate Python, C++, Perl, Lisp and XRC (wxWidgets' XML resources) code.

However, if you need write for yourself any single word by means of *wxPython* as you said you can use wxNotebook, you can use [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/15/wxpython-a-simple-notebook-example/) code:

```
import random
import wx

class TabPanel(wx.Panel):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        colors = ["red", "blue", "gray", "yellow", "green"]
        self.SetBackgroundColour(random.choice(colors))

        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
 class DemoFrame(wx.Frame):
    """
    Frame that holds all other widgets
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""        
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, 
                          "Notebook Tutorial",
                          size=(600,400)
                          )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(panel)
        tabOne = TabPanel(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabOne, "Tab 1")

        tabTwo = TabPanel(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(tabTwo, "Tab 2")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = DemoFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: thank you very much . This is exactly what I was looking for . But i think you've not specified the work of button **press me** to link into new notebook page . Can you please do that. That would be great . Thanks alot again!!!

Comment: Actually button *press me* is an example and you can skip that. Now you have different items (pages) so for each one you are allowed to add a number of buttons and other stuffs separately.